# Play Music And Sound Effects On Top Of Each other (PyGame)

Tags: python, audio, pygame, mixer

I was wondering if it is possible to play a sound over a different sound using the pygame mixer. So for example I would have quiet background music playing, and then something happens and another sound played on top if it. Currently for the background music  I use this:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("Audio Assets//bob.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

But if I play another sound in a method the background music completely stops and doesn't start over again. Is it possible to play two sound on top of eachother?

Edit: I am now wondering how I could play a sound while a show and image in Tkinter, here is my code for showing the image:

```
def one():
    pone = PhotoImage(file="Image Assets//DEAD.gif")
    labelone = Label(root, image=pone)
    labelone.image = pone
    labelone.pack(pady=70)
    labelone.after(2000, labelone.destroy)
```

As you can see the image gets shown and then destroyed after 2 seconds. How would I be able to play audio during those seconds using the channels and mixer?

EDIT 2: It was very simple, I just placed `pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound('sound\gun_fire.wav'), maxtime=600)` at the end of the method and it plays as the image is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to play sound effects over music (or sound effects over other sound effects), you can use Channels. for example:

```
# initialize
pygame.mixer.pre_init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()

# start playing the background music
pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sound', 'main_theme.wav'))
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.3)
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)  # loop forever
```

Then later in the code, you can play sound effects through Channels:

```
# play a sound on channel 0 with a max time of 600 milliseconds
pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound('sound\gun_fire.wav'), maxtime=600)

# you can play a longer sound on another channel and they won't conflict
pygame.mixer.Channel(1).play(pygame.mixer.Sound("sound\death.wav"), maxtime=2000)
```

For more information on [Channels](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel)

if you are looking to set the volume of an individual channel, you can use the [set_volume()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel.set_volume) function:

```
channel.set_volume(0.5)  # play at 50% volume
```

Comment: I'll accept the answer when I get it to work, I am not at home currently and can't test it, thanks anyways.

Comment: Ok I just got home and I have a question, how I would play a sound while i'm showing an image with Tkinter. I tried but I can only get it to play before and after the image is displayed. I will edit the question.

Comment: I am not sure i follow. If you can post more code regarding the issue i can try to offer more assistance

Comment: Im sorry, I didn't explain it thoroughly. Essentially I am using Tkinter for my GUI and I wanted to use PyGame's audio because it seemed the simplest. Essentially I would like to have a picture displayed for 2 seconds which the code I put in the OP does. Now I would like to play audio while that picture is shown. If it is still not clear I don't mind posting a new question.

Comment: Oh nvm, I figured it out. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Oh, actually i'm so sorry to bother but I have one more question, how would one change the volume of a particular channel?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if you can have individual volumes for each channel. You might have to change the volume through the music mixer each time. I will have to investigate further

Comment: I'll do some research too.

Comment: I updated the answer to include setting the volume for Channels. I haven't tested anything with it though